# Vault Spring client keeps its connectivity to vault

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I have a spring-boot application that uses vault to keep its secrets.
The connection to vault is by a dedicated class with the @VaultPropertySource annotation. The connectivity configuration is in bootstrap.yaml file.
I need the connection only on application startup to read all the secrets, but I see that spring keeps checking the connectivity all over the application life, so if I shut down the vault, my application is crashed because a connectivity lost.
So my question is, how can I configure spring to not keep the connectivity after the application startup.

Note: I know the fail-fast configuration, but this is very general configuration. I want that my application will fail if there is no connection on startup to read the secrets, but I don't want to be depend on vault all over the application life.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we have configured in our setup with **spring config server**:

Add **dependency info for clients in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Add **vault configuration in bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${CONFIG_SERVER_URI}
      username: ****
      password: ****
    vault:
      uri: ${VAULT_URI}
      authentication: token
      token: ${SPRING_CLOUD_VAULT_TOKEN}
  application:
    name: APP-NAME
```

**Provide the required arguments while running the jar**.

```
exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar -Drun.arguments=--spring.cloud.config.uri=${CONFIG_SERVER_URI} \
     -Drun.arguments=--spring.cloud.vault.uri=${VAULT_URI} \
     -Dspring.cloud.vault.token=${SPRING_CLOUD_VAULT_TOKEN} \
     APP-NAME.jar
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now, if your vault is shutting down, do you see any error in your application?

Comment: No, it has no dependency as all the required secrets are fetched from Vault during app startup.

Comment: Thank you. Actually configuration is similar except to the config part that is in application.properties file. I think that my problem is raised from my application itself. Maybe my vault properties class is created again and again over application life.